# Can't include a field with $project operator in a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB database I have a collection called test that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5774f2807f93c094a6691506"),
    "name" : "jack",
    "city" : "LA",
    "age" : 30.0,
    "cars" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5774f2be7f93c094a6691507"),
    "name" : "jack",
    "city" : "LA",
    "age" : 40.0,
    "cars" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5774f2ed7f93c094a6691508"),
    "name" : "peter",
    "city" : "London",
    "age" : 35.0,
    "cars" : 1
}
```

I have made a query which groups the people by name and city and only displays the oldest element of each group. In addition it only displays the guys that have at least a car. The query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [

                {
                    "$match":{"cars":{$ne:0}}
                },
                {
                    "$group": { "_id": { name: "$name", city: "$city" }, "age":{$max:"$age"}}
                }
                ,
                {
                    "$project":{"age":1, "name":"$_id.name", "city":"$_id.city", "cars":true}
                }
       ] )
```

After executing the above query I get the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "peter",
        "city" : "London"
    },
    "age" : 35.0,
    "name" : "peter",
    "city" : "London"
}
```

It's correct because peter is the only guy that owns a car. The problem is that it doesn't display the "cars" field. As you can see in the query there is a $project operator and the "cars" field is set to true. So it should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Does adding cars at the grouping stage help? I am assuming you need to count them.

```
"$group": {
  "_id": { name: "$name", city: "$city" },
  "age": { $max:"$age" }
  "cars": { $sum:"$cars" }
}
```

The input of the project stage is the output of the grouping stage. In your original query, there was no cars field available in this input.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to "$push" cars into an array while grouping the data.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [

                {
                    "$match":{"cars":{$ne:0}}
                },
                {
                    "$group": { "_id": { name: "$name", city: "$city" }, 
                                       cars : {$push : "$cars"}, "age":{$max:"$age"}}
                }
                ,
                {
                    "$project":{"age":1, "name":"$_id.name", "city":"$_id.city", "cars":true}
                }
       ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not displayed because it's not created in the previous pipeline stage. To understand how the aggregation pipeline works, treat the the aggregation operation as you would with any database system.

The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless we use any of the aggregation functions.

The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. In this instance, to generate a car field you would have to use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator to return the top document fields in the group.

This works well when the documents getting into that **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step are ordered, hence the need for a **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline before the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** for ordering. You can then apply the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator to the ordered group to get the maximum (which is essentially the top document in the ordered group, with its corresponding car value).

A correct pipeline that returns the desired field would look like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "cars": { "$ne": 0 } } },
    { "$sort": { "name": 1, "city": 1, "age": -1 } }
    {
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { "name": "$name", "city": "$city" }, 
            "age": { "$first": "$age" } ,
            "cars": { "$first": "$cars" } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "age": 1, 
            "cars": 1,
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$_id.name", 
            "city": "$_id.city"             
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: You should use `$gt` in the `$match` expression.